# The server route does not respond to the call (NodeJS + express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets

I am making a server with NodeJS and Express, but when I make a get request to the basic route ('http://localhost:3000/') nothing happens, the request stays waiting. I have reviewed my code many times but I can't find what could be failing. How can I solve it?

PD: I'm also implementing socket.io

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const db = require('./helper/db')

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
      origin: "*"
  }
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.send('Backend NodeJS SO1 Proyecto2');
});

var claves = [];
var total_registros = 0;
var semestre_cursos = [];

async function consultarRedis() {

  const client = await createClient({
    url: 'redis://172.17.0.3:6379'
  })
  .on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
  .connect();

  total_registros = await client.get('total_registros');
  console.log(total_registros)

}

async function consultarRedisSemestre() {
  semestre_cursos = [];
  const client = await createClient({
    url: 'redis://172.17.0.3:6379'
  })
  .on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
  .connect();

  var temp = 0;
  for(var clave of claves){
    try{
      temp = await client.hGet('cursos_semestres', clave)
      semestre_cursos.push(parseInt(temp))
    }catch(error){
      console.error(`Error al consultar Redis para la clave "${clave}":`, error)
    }
  }
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Cliente conectado');

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    consultarRedis();
    socket.emit('total_registros', total_registros);
  }, 1000);

  // Manejar desconexiones de socket.io
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('Cliente desconectado');
  });

  socket.on('selectedSemester', (semestreSeleccionado) => {
    claves = [];
    claves.push(`SO1:${semestreSeleccionado}`)
    claves.push(`BD1:${semestreSeleccionado}`)
    claves.push(`LFP:${semestreSeleccionado}`)
    claves.push(`SA:${semestreSeleccionado}`)
    claves.push(`AYD1:${semestreSeleccionado}`)

    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      temp = await consultarRedisSemestre();
      socket.emit('valores_semestre', semestre_cursos);
    }, 1000);
  
  });

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `app.use(cors);`  with `app.use(cors());`

**Best practices:-**

- Always declare your variables with let or const to ensure proper scoping.
- Hardcoding Redis server URLs and other configuration values may not be the good for production applications. Consider using environment variables to handle such settings dynamically.

Comment: Thank you!!!! app.use(cors()) solved the problem, I didn't expect the solution to be so simple!